# Is there a standard for localized locale codes?

Tags: localization

I am currently working on a project that would benefit from localized locale codes. For example, RFC 5646 and the parent-standard BCP 47 define locale codes for various locales, such as en-GB for British English and zh-Hans-SG for Singaporean Chinese using simplified Chinese characters. Unfortunately, these codes use only a small subset of the latin alphabet.

I am looking for a similar standard or commonly used system that defines a set of language codes in the respective writing system of each language (somewhat akin to an autoglossonym).

EDIT: I am strictly seeking localized locale codes since in the problem's context (URI i18n/l10n), it would be unreasonable to use an autoglossonym or other verbose equivalent.

Comment: What advantage would it have if it's in the native writing system of each language? Some languages have many native writing systems (as in: Cyrillic, Latin and Arabic alphabets for some Turkic and Iranian langs, dozens for Mongolian). Plus, be aware dialect borders almost never follow political ones. E.g. Western Venezuela's Spanish dialects are closer to Eastern Colombian ones than each is to their respective capital's speech, but you only see lists "CO-Spanish" and "VE-Spanish" in the localizations.

Comment: While I agree that dialects are often left to the wayside in such cases, generalized localizations are better than no localizations at all (a question of economics for corporations, of course).

As for the advantage, it is a question of readability, in my opinion. Would a native japanese reader more clearly understand "Japanese" or "日本語". I would argue that the latter is more convivial.

Comment: Don't know of any such standard, don't know if it's even feasible save for languages not very spread - a name or another can even have political repercussions: Should Spanish be "castellano" or "español"? Probably what Wikipedia calls a language in its native script is the closest to a standard...

Comment: I would be very cautious with localized locale codes. Locale codes, like [ISO 639-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-3) for languages, really ought to be machine-readable at the expense of human-readability. Not conforming to a standard scheme would create many more problems than the single aesthetic one it would solve.

Comment: This "small subset of the latin alphabet" is called ["ASCII"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) and it's used for codes for a fortunate reason, that almost every other character set / encoding / codepage includes ASCII as an exact subset so converting encodings will never mess them up. What is unfortunate about this?

Comment: hippietrail: Actually, the language code defined in the indicated standards do not require ASCII encoding. There are plenty of encodings that do not correlate with the ASCII caracter set. The small subset of latin alphabet to which I was referring is the letters A-Z and a-z, in addition to the dash caracter.

Comment: limetom: The question of machine readability is valid if the locale code is never displayed. However, my question was intended to be geared towards complete i18n/l10n of websites, including URI's, in which many corporate websites include the current locale code in the URI. In such a case, a localized code would be much better suited than an autoglossonym. The conversion from such a localized code to the RFC or BCP standards could be accomplished with a fairly straightforward table lookup.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about technical issues/programming.

Answer (score 1):

Locale codes as specified by RFC 5656 and BCP 47 are meant to be machine parseable. Thus, en-GB is "English (Great Britain)" and zh-Hans-SG is "Chinese (Singapore, Simplified Chinese Script)".

They are designed so that web pages, e-books and other documents can specify the language and script they are written in in a standard way.

Thus, each language, script and country is given a unique code from the respective standards and collated in the IANA Language Subtag Registry (http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry).

For a localized version of this, you are better off mapping the codes to a localized name (e.g. localizing the Description field of the subtag registry database, or using a project like iso-codes) and formatting that in a presentable way, keeping the locale code as an internal representation.

Comment: See my comment above in response to limetom's comment to my original question. In short, an autoglossonym cannot be used in the problem context, leading to the requirement of a localized locale code.